# What does $PS_STOCK_MANAGEMENT refer to? Prestashop

Tags: smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.6

In the default theme provided with Prestashop 1.6.0.6, there are several times I found this variable. An example:

```
{if $PS_STOCK_MANAGEMENT}
    <!-- availability -->
    <p class="warning_inline" id="last_quantities"{if ($product->quantity > $last_qties || $product->quantity <= 0) || $allow_oosp || !$product->available_for_order || $PS_CATALOG_MODE} style="display: none"{/if} >{l s='Warning: Last items in stock!'}</p>

{/if}
```

What this variable is referring to?

Can you please provide me with a links to a reference to such variables, or any documentation explaining them? I unfortunately don't find such info in the web. Highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it refers to the setting "Enable stock management" in `Preferes > Products > Products Stock". It's there to check whether quantity information of a product is available or not.

For more information about the setting, you can read here: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Products+Preferences

Comment: Thank you. Is there alternatively to the link provided a document that shows thoses variables for developpers??

Comment: There isn't, as I am aware of. You can add `{debug}` to a template file to see all the variables available in a template. Most of the time the variable's name is self-documentary, otherwise you can look in the controller to see how they are setup, for example: https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6/classes/controller/FrontController.php#L322

Comment: Nice, I will try  `{debug}` inside my template. One another clarification please: if we take the example of the variable `$allow_oops`, I should look in the `productController`, right? (sush variables are not self explanatory I guess :-) ). Thanks again

Comment: I believe it is `$allow_oosp`, which stand for `Out of Stock Purchase`. The first time I see it just use `grep` or any search-in-project tool and search for it, the result was something like `./classes/Cart.php:673: $row['allow_oosp'] = Product::isAvailableWhenOutOfStock($row['out_of_stock']);`. If you know the abbreviation then it's easier.